# Windows 10 Settings app crashes when trying to remove account used by other apps

Tags: windows, windows-10, crash

Circled by red you can see the "remove" button. Now when I press it asks for confirmation. After I confirm the Settings crashes.
[image]
I used that account to login into Store app. I tried to sign-out and remove the account but the problem still persists.
Tried in **Safe-mode** to remove the account and the problem still persists.

I have used a program previously (after I have installed Windows 10 Pro x64) to delete bundled apps and all that is left is:
*Calculator;
*Contact Support;
*Photo;
*Insider Hub;
*Store;
*Edge;
*Search;
*Settings:
*Windows Feedback.

I am using Windows Defender as protection.
I have used a tool called Spybot Anti-beacon to turn-off Windows 10 tracking (selected all options).
I have a local account and there are 3 accounts in total including mine.

**Event log:**

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          26.07.2016 23:18:36
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DESKTOP-MAQQR8C
Description:
Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe, version: 10.0.10586.11, time stamp: 0x56457cb1
Faulting module name: twinapi.appcore.dll, version: 10.0.10586.494, time stamp: 0x5775e2d9
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x000000000004b1c9
Faulting process id: 0xb4c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1e779eaf1d518
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll
Report Id: 6ab3aaf4-9be2-401c-a130-47e6b1eb41c0
Faulting package full name: windows.immersivecontrolpanel_6.2.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-26T20:18:36.069873600Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1401</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-MAQQR8C</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>SystemSettings.exe</Data>
    <Data>10.0.10586.11</Data>
    <Data>56457cb1</Data>
    <Data>twinapi.appcore.dll</Data>
    <Data>10.0.10586.494</Data>
    <Data>5775e2d9</Data>
    <Data>c000027b</Data>
    <Data>000000000004b1c9</Data>
    <Data>b4c</Data>
    <Data>01d1e779eaf1d518</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll</Data>
    <Data>6ab3aaf4-9be2-401c-a130-47e6b1eb41c0</Data>
    <Data>windows.immersivecontrolpanel_6.2.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy</Data>
    <Data>microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>


Version=1
EventType=MoAppCrash
EventTime=131140386549475501
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=131140388187708911
ReportIdentifier=d9a28d57-536f-11e6-a91b-84a6c85776b3
IntegratorReportIdentifier=b90b90c7-aa30-4936-8bc7-717d87b66592
NsAppName=praid:microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Package Full Name
Sig[0].Value=windows.immersivecontrolpanel_6.2.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Sig[1].Name=Application Name
Sig[1].Value=praid:microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
Sig[2].Name=Application Version
Sig[2].Value=10.0.10586.11
Sig[3].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[3].Value=56457cb1
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[4].Value=combase.dll
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[5].Value=10.0.10586.103
Sig[6].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[6].Value=56a849ab
Sig[7].Name=Exception Code
Sig[7].Value=80070422
Sig[8].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[8].Value=00000000000324cd
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.10586.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1048
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=1a0d
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=1a0d9967bd981599c1f851e5f3a96ff5
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=6b89
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=6b89f7b73f993f3738b9de48b9de51ac
UI[2]=C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\system32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\system32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\system32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\system32\windows.storage.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\system32\advapi32.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\system32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\system32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\system32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\system32\powrprof.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\system32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CoreMessaging.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\Bcp47Langs.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.10586.494_none_a2d8b04ea53e3145\Comctl32.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\PROPSYS.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MrmCoreR.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wincorlib.DLL
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\Telemetry.Desktop.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\System32\ActXPrxy.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\igd10umd64.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d2d1.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\System32\dcomp.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettingsViewModel.Desktop.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\system32\CoreUIComponents.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Immersive.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\system32\DataExchange.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sppc.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\policymanager.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcp110_win.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINSTA.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\System32\ieproxy.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwrite.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Globalization.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.Phone.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\system32\twinapi.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msftedit.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\globinputhost.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NInput.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.StateRepository.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\StateRepository.Core.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NcaApi.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\Windows\system32\credprovhost.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\samcli.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\netutils.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\Windows\System32\OneBackupHandler.dll
LoadedModule[77]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\Windows\System32\fhsettingsprovider.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\fhsvcctl.dll
LoadedModule[80]=C:\Windows\System32\fhcfg.dll
LoadedModule[81]=C:\Windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[82]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wevtapi.dll
LoadedModule[83]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\EFSUTIL.dll
LoadedModule[84]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\XmlLite.dll
LoadedModule[85]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SRVCLI.DLL
LoadedModule[86]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll
LoadedModule[87]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DSROLE.dll
LoadedModule[88]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll
LoadedModule[89]=C:\Windows\System32\sdengin2.dll
LoadedModule[90]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msi.dll
LoadedModule[91]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SPP.dll
LoadedModule[92]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VSSAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[93]=C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[94]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VssTrace.DLL
LoadedModule[95]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcd.dll
LoadedModule[96]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
LoadedModule[97]=C:\Windows\system32\directmanipulation.dll
LoadedModule[98]=C:\Windows\System32\threadpoolwinrt.dll
LoadedModule[99]=C:\Windows\System32\SettingsHandlers_nt.dll
LoadedModule[100]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VEEventDispatcher.dll
LoadedModule[101]=C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\DataLayer.dll
LoadedModule[102]=C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll
LoadedModule[103]=C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\mpclient.dll
LoadedModule[104]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[105]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[106]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\gpapi.dll
LoadedModule[107]=C:\Windows\System32\TokenBroker.dll
LoadedModule[108]=C:\Windows\System32\SettingsHandlers_UserAccount.dll
LoadedModule[109]=C:\Windows\System32\IDStore.dll
LoadedModule[110]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SAMLIB.dll
LoadedModule[111]=C:\Windows\System32\shacct.dll
LoadedModule[112]=C:\Windows\System32\usercpl.dll
LoadedModule[113]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntshrui.dll
LoadedModule[114]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wkscli.dll
LoadedModule[115]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\logoncli.dll
LoadedModule[116]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\credui.dll
LoadedModule[117]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DUI70.dll
LoadedModule[118]=C:\Windows\system32\shgina.dll
LoadedModule[119]=C:\Windows\System32\usermgrproxy.dll
LoadedModule[120]=C:\Windows\System32\vaultcli.dll
LoadedModule[121]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profext.dll
LoadedModule[122]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Web.dll
LoadedModule[123]=C:\Windows\system32\SettingSyncCore.dll
LoadedModule[124]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[125]=C:\Windows\System32\OneDriveSettingSyncProvider.dll
LoadedModule[126]=C:\Windows\system32\ConnectedAccountState.dll
LoadedModule[127]=C:\Windows\System32\thumbcache.dll
LoadedModule[128]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\edputil.dll
LoadedModule[129]=C:\Windows\system32\windowscodecs.dll
LoadedModule[130]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\PhotoMetadataHandler.dll
LoadedModule[131]=C:\Windows\System32\StructuredQuery.dll
LoadedModule[132]=C:\Windows\system32\Windows.Storage.Search.dll
LoadedModule[133]=C:\Windows\system32\AccountsRT.dll
LoadedModule[134]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\APHostClient.dll
LoadedModule[135]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\UserDataPlatformHelperUtil.dll
LoadedModule[136]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dsreg.dll
LoadedModule[137]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll
LoadedModule[138]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[139]=C:\Windows\System32\UIAnimation.dll
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=MoAppCrash
AppName=windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
AppPath=C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=EF99997B436A3187AC3BA5E0C6F1EC91
```

Comment: Was there any other errors besides that one, somtimes a error will generate more than one entry. Be sure to highlight the text and press the button that looks like `{ }` in the toolbar to format the text nicely when you paste it in to your question.

Comment: I really have no idea, however i did see for the same error code you got with windows updates it means that the windows module installer in services needs to be set to automatic. Maybe it might help, beyond that I don't think I can be more help.

Comment: create a dump and share the zipped dm: http://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Spybot **Anti-Beacon.** I disabled **all options** from it and I restarted the system. Then I could delete the account without any crash. For security purposes I disabled the internet before I did that.